# Can I use data from JTable for my Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm new in using Jasper and I'm practicing of creating programs for accounting. Jasper helps me to generate nice reports using SQL queries, but is there a any way to generate report using data's from jtable? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can build a JRDataSource from a table model using [JRTableModelDataSource](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/data/JRTableModelDataSource.html).

The names of the fields are the names of the columns returned by `TableModel.getColumnNames()`. You may also use `COLUMN_<index>` as field name.